# linux disable laptop speakers

Tags: linux, audio

I exclusively use headphones on my laptop.  When I unplug the power adapter and headphones to put my laptop away at school, the music starts blaring out of the built-in speakers.  Can I just disable the built in speakers, or do I always have to mute the speakers before I unplug the headphones?  My laptop is set to not sleep (just screen off) when I close the lid because I want my code to continue to compile while walking to my next class.

Answer (score 0):

run

> modprobe -r pcspkr

run

> sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and add `blacklist pcspkr`.

Comment: it's not a pcspkr.  this line is already in blacklist.conf.  adding it again will do nothing.

Comment: what about snd_pcsp

Comment: amixer -c<num> set <SCONTROL> mute